# Closure and the openness of a set

Tags: general-topology

> Determine the closure of the set $A =\{(x,y) \in B \mid x+y > 1 \}$ in $B$, where $B$ is the open unit disk. Is the set open or closed?

For the closure I got that

$$\begin{align*}
\operatorname{cl_{B}}A &= B \cap \overline{A}\\
&= \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} \mid x^2+y^2 < 1 \} \cap \{(x,y) \in B \mid x+y\geqslant 1\}\\
&= \{(x,y) \in B \mid x+y\geqslant 1\}\,.
\end{align*}$$

But is the set $A$ neccessarily open?

Comment: @Surb: No, it is not: $A$ is open in $\Bbb R^2$ and hence in $B$, since it is the intersection of the open unit disk and the open half plane lying above the line $x+y=1$.

Comment: $A$ is open in $B.$ Every point of $A \cap B$ is an interior point of $B.$